# Итерация по объектам модуля в Python

Tags: python, модули

У меня много классов в модуле, к параметрам которых нужно обращаться в другом модуле. Можно ли как-то по ним итерироваться? Примерно так:

```
import module
    
for mod in module:
    print(mod.a)
```

Но следующий код выдает ошибку, что module не итерируемый объект. Как правильнее сделать это без обращения к кадому классу отдельно (типа module.classA.a)?

Comment: `for mod in dir(module): print(getattr(module, mod).a)`

Comment: точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и сказал @andreimal, решенем является:

```
for mod in dir(module): print(getattr(module, mod).a)
```